# tf.data: create a Dataset from a list of Numpy arrays of different shape

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a list of Numpy arrays of different shape.

I need to create a Dataset, so that each time an element is requested I get a tensor with the shape and values of the given Numpy array.

How can I achieve this?

This is *NOT* working:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(list_of_arrays)
```

since you get, as expected:

> Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor.

p.s. I know that it will not be possible to batch a Dataset with elements of different shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried converting initially to a ragged tensor?

```
tensor_with_from_dimensions = tf.ragged.constant([[1, 2], [3], [4, 5, 6]])
```

Bear in mind that:

> All scalar values in pylist must have the same nesting depth K, and
> the returned RaggedTensor will have rank K. If pylist contains no
> scalar values, then K is one greater than the maximum depth of empty
> lists in pylist. All scalar values in pylist must be compatible with
> dtype.

You can read more about it here : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ragged/constant

Answer (score 3):

I've accepted the solution from Timbus Calin since is the more compact, but I've found another way that provides a lot of flexibility and its worth mentioning here.

Its based on generators:

```
def create_generator(list_of_arrays):
    for i in list_of_arrays:
        yield i

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: create_generator(list_of_arrays),output_types= tf.float32, output_shapes=(None,4))
```